# raytracer output is black image

Tags: c++, raytracing

I am currently trying to implement a raytracer. Actually, I try to rearrange the raytracer that we did last year (in opengl, glew, qt (this prt written by our teacher) and c++) onto juste a simple basic raytracer in c++. 
So the camera is not handled anymore by opengl so I wrote one like this:

```
class Camera{
  public:
    inline Camera() : camPos(Vec3Df(0.0f ,0.0f ,-3.0f)), direction(Vec3Df(0.0f, 1.0f,   2.0f)),upVector(Vec3Df(0.0f ,0.0f ,0.0f)), rightVector(Vec3Df(0.0f ,0.0f ,0.0f)){ }  
    inline const Vec3Df & getCamPos () const { return camPos; }
    inline const Vec3Df & getDirection () const { return direction; }
    inline const Vec3Df & getUpVector () const { return upVector; }
    inline const Vec3Df & getRightVector () const { return rightVector; }

  private:
    Vec3Df camPos;
    Vec3Df direction;
    Vec3Df upVector;
    Vec3Df rightVector;
};
```

I don't know if it's correct, by I found that people put random coordinates for position and direction.

The teacher also implemented a loader for .off files to load an object with its vertices and triangles.

The methods for intersection with a triangle work because it work this the last project, but here, now that I handle the camera, it doesn't find any intersection at all and I have a black image as output.

Could someone help me please? or advise me?

Comment: Is it supposed to output to a file or to an application window? Have you put breakpoints in your collision code to make sure it is actually intersecting triangles?  We'll need to see your triangle setup code as well to be able to make sure your viewport can see your triangle to render it.

Comment: I make a matrix and I store in every pixel the color. I put breakpoints and I understood that the image is black because the ray seem to intersect no triangle at all.

Comment: Do you want me to put the code for the intersections?

Comment: Yes, we need to see the intersection code as well as a vector for a test ray and the triangle that you are trying to intersect to make a sort of unit test.

Comment: I hope this will work: [link](http://pastebin.com/7nSLtKMU)

Comment: Random coordinates for the direction of the camera? I don't think so, if you put your camera looking the wrong direction your rays won't intersect anything at all; thus leaving you with a black image.

Comment: But I don't understand how can I tell the camera where to look for the object?

Comment: @Ekica You know where the object is. Look at it.

Comment: @molbdnilo I may dumb, but my object is defined bu multiple vertices, so there is no central point. How can i say to the camera which point to look at?

Comment: You can put your camera in a random position that is not too far from your object (you know where it is right?), then the direction is formed by the vector that joins the camera and the object.

Comment: @Ekica You can calculate a bounding box, and consider its center as your object's center

Comment: Oh i never thought I could use the bounding box for that! But if I have multiple objects in the scene, do I calculate the bounding box of all object and then consider the center of this giant bounding box?